# multiple use of split

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I have two equations that I would like to split (with a `split` command) but have them both lined up; i.e., something like

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a&=xxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
 &=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\label{1}
\intertext{and}
\begin{split}
b&=yyyyyyyyyyyyy\\
 &=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy\label{2}
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

I want the `split` command so that the equation labels are centered between the two lines, and the `align` command so that all four equal signs are lined up.  What I just tried doesn't work.  I tried nesting  `aligned` within `align`, but the four equal signs were not lined up.

Comment: Please post a full minimal example that others can just copy'n'paste and try without having to add anything. Makes it a lot easier to help.

Comment: Plus I do not quite get what you are trying to do. Note that `split` onlt handles a single `&` per line, if you need more, then use `aligned` (also not that the number of `&`'s per line is (2x number of alignments -1) )

Comment: BTW: if you remember to end the first `split`, then your sniplet works just fine

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an `\end{split}` statement before `\intertext`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align" and "split" environments and "\intertext" macro
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a&=xxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
 &=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\label{1}
\end{split}  % <--- new
\intertext{and}
\begin{split}
b&=yyyyyyyyyyyyy\\
 &=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy\label{2}
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```